# 2- 5: Writing PL/SQL Executable Statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

Examine the following code and then answer the question.

```
DECLARE  v_number   NUMBER; 
v_boolean  BOOLEAN;
BEGIN  v_number := 25; 
 v_boolean := NOT(v_number > 30);
END;
```

What value is assigned to v_boolean?

I don't know how to display the output, anyone can give me the syntax?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923485/converting-boolean-to-varchar2

Comment: What "output" do you need to display? The question is "what value is assigned", not "display the value assigned to...". Without displaying anything, just in your head, can you figure out what value will be assigned to `v_boolean`?

Comment: yes but I want to display it in sql, and I don;t know how to out the output

Comment: Abra can you retype the syintax ? I still don't understand

Comment: _"I don;t know how to out the output"_   take a look at dbms_output.put_line.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_output.htm#TTPLP036

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_boolean=' || CASE WHEN v_boolean=TRUE THEN 'TRUE' WHEN v_boolean=FALSE THEN 'FALSE' WHEN v_boolean IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '?????' END);`